# What ever became of the meeting with SE staff about the "future of Serverfault"?

Tags: discussion

I was going to ask this is in chat but figured it was better served if the community-at-large got to see the results of the meeting, what was discussed, etc.

This is in regards to this Meta post: [Questions to ask the SE staff regarding the future of ServerFault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5744/questions-to-ask-the-se-staff-regarding-the-future-of-serverfault)

There were multiple questions that were supposed to be posed and the SE staff seemed willing to have an open teleconference to discuss action items, etc.

I can't find another Meta post regarding the outcome and what all was discussed by whom, etc.

I'm hoping Chopper3 or someone that attended (maybe an SE Staff member?) could shed some light on it for the community.

(if it's already been posted, I guess link it here and I'll admit my failed search abilities)

Comment: At least one thing came of it http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5850/should-folks-have-to-click-through-an-interstitial-page-to-ask-questions-on-serv but nothing else appears to have been published.

Comment: Basically I took notes then got too busy to edit and publish them, I should be able to do that here once I get a bit of time.

Comment: Iain already linked to the only status-completed thing to come out of it; I have something else on my list for probably next spring. If @Chopper3 still has notes, I'll leave it to him.

Comment: @Shog9: Any chance of you advancing spring somewhat ? We're into our [eternal weekend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) now and things are getting very bad :(

Comment: @Iain - I was actually about to ask him and Chopper again for updates, but figured it might have gotten pushed down the pile of to-do's again.

Comment: @TheCleaner: Today has been especially bad :(

Comment: @Iain: the bulk of what I want to do will take serious time to design and implement, but there's one small part I should be able to expedite; will update you as I'm able to.

Comment: @Iain: [thoughts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6105/what-server-fault-specific-advice-should-we-give-folks-asking-questions-here)

Comment: Is there any chance we can revisit these questions with the StackExchange Community staff? They seem more topical than ever today.

Answer (score 5):

I think this has been lost in the mists of time.

Comment: Thanks for reviving this.  I look forward to visiting this again in a year. :)

Comment: I only revived it because I needed a 200th answer.

Comment: I wish Shog or someone on staff would answer it for selfish reasons...that would suffice enough for me.