# What Server Fault-specific advice should we give folks asking questions here?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

As of a few weeks ago, the "unclear what you're asking" close reason now links to [a page in the help center](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask):

[image: closed as unclear banner]

The moderators here can edit this page to customize it. So my questions are,

1. Should they do so?
2. What should they add or change to make it more useful to folks asking questions here?

Note that this page is currently *very* similar to [a different page](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask), one that we modified slightly [a few months back](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5850/should-folks-have-to-click-through-an-interstitial-page-to-ask-questions-on-serv). The results of that change weren't very impressive, and frankly I don't expect the results of this one to be noticeable either - very, very few people care enough to click through to the guidance linked to on these close reasons.

That said, it could provide a useful guide for folks struggling to ask Server Fault questions, if y'all care to make it one. Thoughts?

Comment: We also link to this page in one of the mod messages, so I am definitely interested in customizing it.

Comment: How effective are the links in the current close reasons? How many OPs for example read the How to Ask page linked to in the reason you quote after their question is closed ? What about the other helpful links for other close reasons ?

Comment: The vast, vast, vast majority of people who ask the really bad questions have (somehow) managed to avoid reading the SF FAQ, looking around the site even a little, or even consulting Google.  And when ServerFault doesn't provide them "teh codez for fixing [foo]" they vanish, never to be seen on ServerFault again.  So while we can provide some more helpful text, I am in complete agreement with Iain that it's not something worth putting much effort into.  Anyone who actually cares about asking better questions has no problems finding the resources we already have for that purpose.

Comment: Not particularly effective, @Iain. I've been struggling a bit to get accurate numbers on how many folks actually follow these links, but 1-2% is a rough estimate. The hard truth is that relatively few people will read *anything* that you put in front of them - you can hope to target the conscientious minority, and nothing more.

Comment: @Shog9: That's actually worse than I would have guessed. Perhaps it's time to stop wasting time on people who don't want to help themselves and direct energies towards the people who want to make this a better place ?

Comment: Well, any time you do something like this you have to assume you're doing it for the productive minority, @Iain - you can't get blood from a turnip. Y'all seem to have an exceptionally difficult time attracting that minority, but Sturgeon's Law applies pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @Shog9 If we could just stop the turnips from asking questions though ...

Comment: A month passes, it'll soon be spring at this rate ... is anything going to happen here ?

Comment: Tempus fugit, another month passes with no apparent movement on this. Is anything likely to happen? At least it's spring so we have the other idea you have to look forward too.

Comment: @Iain [4 to 6 weeks](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) (I've got a diamond, I'm allowed to use that excuse right?) -- Are there any more of these hanging around?

Comment: @voretaq7: Not that I'm aware of but as [Michael notes](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6105/what-server-fault-specific-advice-should-we-give-folks-asking-questions-here#comment12324_6105) there is a mod message that may need tweaking.

Answer (score 12):

I recently stole Jon Skeet's excellent check list and [modified it for use on Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question). I've left a link to it in quite a few comments recently and on a several occasions people have responded positively to it. Perhaps it (or something similar) could be used?

I think this has the advantage over @voretaq7's excellent [How can I ask a better question ...](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) simply because there is less to read but that should be considerer too.

---

The people who need to read this are least likely to be bothered so I don't think there should be a lot of effort put into this.

Comment: +1 Unfortunately I have to agree with the last part.

Comment: @ChrisS: Sadly, it will most likely just become a link target for the ever decreasing number of people who care to point the clueless at.

Comment: I basically snarfed the major points from the default page and your checklist (tried to distill it down to 5 items, wound up with 6) and added links to some of the canonical meta questions on how to write a decent (main site) question. It all fits on one of my screens, so hopefully it won't be too intimidating for new users and maybe the truly exceptional will follow the links

Comment: @voretaq7: Cheers. I think that it's still too much `wall of text` (the bullet points of the cheklist are better) but given that it will almost never be read by the people who `need` to read it ...

Comment: @Iain I'm definitely open to suggestions for tightening it up - I just didn't want to throw 20 "Do these things noob!" bullet points up - that's almost as intimidating to some folks as a wall of text (and because of markdown's formatting.... *eccentricities* it can be  tough to read too)

Comment: I prefer the imperative style of Do this ... myself but hey we're spending more time that will be useful to the "My server is herping, and I need it to derp, what CPU should I buy?" crowd already.